# Hot to push commit id of a specific submodule to main git repository?

Tags: git, commit, git-submodules, git-commit

I have a repository A, containing two module B and C. When i commit and push from A, B and C commit id are pushed to the main repo. This can be done via a

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'great commit!'
git push origin master
```

Now, I need to push to the main repo the commit id of B, but *not* that of C. If it was a normal file, I would do

```
git add specific_file.ext
git commit -m 'another great commit!'
git push origin master
```

but in case of a submodule, how to reach the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You push and commit submodules exactly the same as files:

```
git add <submodule name>
git commit -m "Updated submodule"
git push origin master
```